# Vim in powershell displays no colors

Tags: powershell, vim

When running vim 8.0 on windows 10 via powershell i can't set any color schemes.
My powershell colors are blue background and white text, and vim also has the same colors and i cant seem to be able to change them.
I am able to set the colors in gVim.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed , the problem was that i forgot to turn on syntax highlighting.
I did this using the command :

```
:syntax on
```